journalctl pager breaks after suspend and return to foreground
This has finally annoyed me enough to look and up and I can find nothing. When using journalctl under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS specifically, if I suspend the process using ^Z and then bring it back to the foreground with fg, I lose the ability to scroll interactively. Instead, each less command becomes line-oriented. So for example, to scroll up one line I hit the up-arrow key and then hit <Enter> to effectuate it. Or space-enter to page down; or Ctrl+R-enter to repaint, etc. Needless to say, this seems very broken.
This question journalctl - stop following without exiting pager mentions the flags journalctl passes to less and I've tried to modify these (using -X, for example, within less and then suspending/resuming the task) but I haven't been able been able to restore the default non-line oriented behavior.
Is there a fix for this or does it just happen to me? Surely I can't be the only person bothered by this. Is it fixed in a later version?
# journalctl --version
systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.12)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified

